# How does java implements uuid v2?

Tags: java, uuid

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_2_%28date-time_and_MAC_address,_DCE_security_version%29):

> Version-2 UUIDs are similar to version 1, except that the least significant 8 bits of the clock sequence are replaced by a "local domain" number, and the least significant 32 bits of the timestamp are replaced by an integer identifier meaningful within the specified local domain. On POSIX systems, local-domain numbers 0 and 1 are for user ids (UIDs) and group ids (GIDs) respectively, and other local-domain numbers are site-defined. On non-POSIX systems, all local domain numbers are site-defined.

Now in Java, we can have
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")

I'm confused, how does Java get the "local domain" info?
Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify: GenericGenerator is not something “in Java,” it’s something in a third party library for Java, namely Hibernate.

Comment: See here - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#d0e5294

Comment: @OldProgrammer Good info, in uuid wiki page, actually it has ver 1 to 5. So the uuid2 (random strategy) is actually the uuid ver 4 in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier ?